# Angular shared module in lazyloaded module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular6, angular-router

my app has 2 major modules

```
-- app module
-- dashboard module //lazy loaded
```

app module has container `homeComponent` which holds `navbarComponent` and `heroComponent`
i want to import the `navbarComponent` into a child component of the `dashboard module` so i made the navbar as a shared module, exported the `navbar` and imported the shared module in both the app.module and dashboard module.

this is how routing goes for the app.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'tours',
    loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

and this is for the lazyloaded module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    resolve: {
      tours: PreloadGuard
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'tourDetails',
    component: DetailsComponent,
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    resolve: {
      selectedtour: DetailsGuard
    }
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

the router outlet is in appComponent and at route '', it loads fine the navbar within the home.
but once i navigate to '/tours' which should load the lazyloaded module, it logs an error that HomeComponent is not a part of any module !.

Comment: Have you declared and exported `HomeComponent` in app.module?

Comment: yes and gives the error, however i don't see a reason for exporting the `homeComponent`, it loads fine when you hit it's correlated url, the error fires when you navigate to the lazyloaded module

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz reproducing your issue.. It would be easy to debug

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6dnpe7

this is exactly the structure i have, it works on the stackblitz but never in my app stackblitz on 6.0 and mine on 6.0.7

Comment: That's strange, home component has nothing to do with the tours. It should work if it's declared in Appmodule and no where else.

Comment: and it does work when you first navigate to path  ' '  where it should show !
don't really know what's wrong since i can't replicate it on stackblitz  and it works as expected, i will try to move into a new project